# URL Redirect Masking in PHP

Tags: php, url, cross-domain

I have to show a download link on my site linking it to a file hosted on another domain. I am using the following approach.

1) Pick up the actual URL from the database

```
$fileDownloadLink = "http://whatever.com/thefile.docx";
```

2) Encode the url and pass it as parameter to download.php

```
$shortUrl = base64_encode($fileDownloadLink);
<a href="<?php echo "http://www.mydomain.net/download.php?session=".$shortUrl;?>" target="_blank">Download Please</a>
```

3) Download.php decodes the passed string and try reading the file.

```
<?php 
$str = $_GET["session"];
$path = base64_decode($str);
$mm_type="application/octet-stream";
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
readfile($path);
exit();
?>
```

But I am getting this error from download.php

> Not Acceptable!
>
> An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be
>   found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just redirect in download.php;

```
$str = @$_GET["session"];
$path = base64_decode($shortUrl );
header("Location: $path");
exit();
```